# Meaning of this Conversation

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Person 1: I will send it if you wish.
>
> Person 2: It's okay.

Does Person 2  want Person 1 to send the thing or not?

It is a positive response or a negative one?

Person 1 asking for first time, no promise made previously.

Thing send by Person 1 actually for help of Person 1 only.

And Person 1 feels like Person 2 is not interested.

Comment: If they were both native speakers, Person 1 would say *I will send **it** if you wish*, and Person 2 would use one of the contracted forms ***It's** okay* or ***That's** okay*. Which would still be "ambiguous", but all versions would normally be understood to mean the *current* situation (at which time the item *hasn't* been sent) is "okay", so there's no need to send it. But depending on context, it might mean the current situation (*including* the promise to send it) is okay, in which case it presumably wouldn't be okay if the promise were not in fact carried out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It's okay." is commonly used as a phrase of reassurance.

"You've cut yourself. Should I get a doctor?"
"It's okay. I'll be fine."

So Person 2 is reassuring Person 1 that the situation as it stands is acceptable, and Person 1 does not need to send the item.

Comment: That's only one possible (valid) interpretation. Suppose Person 1 was supposed to send me the package last week, but didn't. If I was Person 2, I might say, "It's okay, take your time," which would probably mean that I still want the package, but I don't want Person 1 to fret because it's being sent late.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear. Person 2 may be saying that it is okay if person 1 sends it, or he may be saying that the situation now, when person 1 has not sent it, is okay.